# How to prevent and OrderedCollection from removing its elements in a #do: loop?

Tags: smalltalk

Consider the following written code:

```
oc do: [:elem | self doSomethingWith: elem]
```

As we all know, the potential problem here is to somehow have `#doSomethingWith:` reach out `oc` (an `OrderedCollection`) and remove some of its elements.

The recommended solution is to write the above as

```
oc copy do: [:elem | self doSomethingWith: elem].
```

Well, yes, but we do not copy all collections every time we enumerate them. Do we?

The actual problem is that the processing of every element can be so difficult to follow that it could end up removing elements without us knowing. In our case above, if some element of `oc` gets somehow removed in the context of `#doSomethingWith:` we will get an `Error`. Won't we?

Not really. The problem will go unnoticed. Look at this example:

```
oc := #(1 2 4) asOrderedCollection.
oc do: [:i | i even ifTrue: [oc remove: i]]
```

In this case we will not get and error and also element `4` will not get processed (i.e., in this case it will not get removed). So we will be **silently skipping elements** from the enumeration.

Why is this? Well, because of the way `#do:` is implemented. Look at Squeak for instance:

```
do: aBlock 
  "Override the superclass for performance reasons."
  | index |
  index := firstIndex.
  [index <= lastIndex]
    whileTrue: 
      [aBlock value: (array at: index).
      index := index + 1]
```

See? `lastIndex` is dynamically checked and that is why we don't go beyond the current size and no `Error` is signaled.

My question is whether this is on purpose or there is a better solution. One that could work would be to save `lastIndex` in a temporary before iterating, but I'm not sure if that would be preferred.

Comment: I'd say don't cut off the branch you're sitting on... Modifying a collection while iterating on it, whatever the language/library is asking for trouble.

Comment: Another point of view is about the programming style. We can mutate the states, but it's not necessarily a good idea. Maybe here we just need to think at a higher level and use select:? Some kinda functional style...Or is it an open-coded optimization of select:? In this case, another question of style. Premature optimizations costs a lot in term of added complexity...

Comment: And having lastIndex in a cache would not be robust. In case we insert some object in the collection we would not iterate on last element neither. And lastIndex would point to an undefined part of the array if we remove from the collection, it would not necessarily trigger an Error, but result in some kind of undefined behavior (Yes, we have UB too...).

Comment: Thanks @aka.nice for you comments. The problem I'm trying to attack happens when the programmer has no practical way to foresee if the `do block` will end up modifying the collection. This issue does not exist when the modification is traceable as it is the case in my example (or even in much less trivial but tractable cases). The issue exists when you cannot tell that in advance because of the nature of the message flow, especially when the flow ends up skipping the processing of some elements.

Comment: If mutation is not avoidable, then consider some kind of linked list structure, cache the next element in the do loop before operating on the current link (or cache the tail before operating on the head, or car/cdr in lisp parlance).

Answer (score 1):

1) as aka.nice already pointed out, it is not a good idea to fetch and remember the initial lastIndex. This will probably make things worse and lead to more trouble.

2) OrderedCollection as provided is not really prepared and does not like the receiver being modified while iterating over it.

3) A better solution would be to collect the elements to remove first, and then after the do:-processing remove them in a second step. However, I understand, that you cannot do this.

Possible solutions for you:

a) create a subclass of OrderedCollection, with redefined do:- and redefined removeXXX- and addXXX- methods. The later ones need to tell the iterator (i.e. the do-method) about what is going on.
(being careful if the index being removed/added is before the current do-index...). 
The notification could be implemented via a proceedable signal/exception, which is signalled in the modifying methods and caught in the do-loop code.

b) create a wrapper class as subclass of Seq.Collection, which has the original collection as instvar and forwards selected messages to its (wrapped) original collection. 
Similar to above, redefine do: and the remove/add methods in this wrapper and do the appropriate actions (.e. again signalling what changed).

Be careful where to keep the state, if the code needs to be reentrant (i.e. if another one does a loop on the wrapped collection); then you would have to keep the state in the do-method and use signals to communicate the changes.

Then enumerate the collection with sth like:

```
(SaveLoopWrapper on:myCollection) do:[: ...
].
```

and make sure that the code which does the remove also sees the wrapper-instance; not myCollection, so that the add/remove are really caught.

If you cannot to the later, there is another hack, coming to my mind: using MethodWrappers, you can change an individual instance's behavior and introduce hooks.
For example, create a subclass of OrderedCollection, with those hooks in, you could:

```
 myColl changeClassTo: TheSubclassWithHooks
```

before iterating.
Then (protected by an ensure:) undo the wrapping after the loop.

Comment: Thanks bla. I'm sorry I couldn't make my question clearer. **I'm not looking for solutions when I know that the do block will possibly modify the collection.** The point I'm trying to make is that sometimes the programmer is unaware of such a possibility because of the intricacies of the do block and therefore the error will go unnoticed, most likely, for along time.

Comment: Detection may be easier to implement (at least in the dialect I use), and may be an option during development/testing.
If the enumerated collection uses an underlying containter, #do: could make this one immutable during the enumeration. If it uses indexed slots, it could make itself immutable during the iteration. 
Smalltalk/X and VisualWorks allow for this. (Squeak/Pharo not, as far as I know; but it should be relatively easy to add immutability eg. using methodWrappers and instance-specific behavior modification).

Comment: Thanks bla. This is the kind of insight I was looking for.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia OK, so do you want a forgiving implementation that would raise an exception or not? immutability is under test in Pharo and soon Squeak, but 1) I'm not sure it's revertible, that would mean the cost of a copy once loop finished 2) that means defensive programming which does not fit the language well. One day or another the user will discover become: so we need to educate. I like the idea of installing instrumented class for test cases if you insist on industrial... But let's teach to not abuse of mutations in the first place.

Comment: @aka.nice, I agree with what you say. All these ideas are helping me understand that the "solution" would be a best practice pattern on the lines of: (1) If your object has a `Collection` in one of its ivars, let the getter answer with a copy of it. (2) Even better, provide enumeration methods for the ivar so that clients do not iterate on the copy. (3) If there is some risk of having re-entrant code that could modify the collection, consider some of the alternatives discussed in the answers to the present question.